# node-gyp rebuild error. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to install `summarizer` module. Here's how the output looks:

```
npm i summarizer
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@3.10.2: This package has been discontinued in favor of lodash@^4.0.0.

> http-sync@0.0.5 install /home/me/node-workspace/node_modules/http-sync
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/me/node-workspace/node_modules/http-sync/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/curllib/curllib.o
../curllib.cc:26:28: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
 class CurlLib : ObjectWrap {                            ^
.
.
.
```

What's causing these errors?

What have I tried?
Deleting `$HOME/.node-gyp` didnt help.
Ref: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809

Comment: What version of node are you running? Run: node -v

Comment: Do you have libcurl headers installed? What system are you running this on?

Comment: @BertrandMarron Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit. I do have `libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Comment: @BertrandMarron check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As weird as it might sound, this answer from the GitHub page helped me solve the issue:

> Deleting the original node_modules folder from my project, then
>   deleting .node-gyp (I did not have .npmrc), restarting, and installing
>   node in my project again with (sudo npm install) worked with no
>   errors.